# Get a screenshot of a specific window with pillow on macos

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshots of a specific chrome window on my mac with python, (not the full screen, but just the chrome window)

I've seen some solutions for Windows, but none for mac yet. I think this is possible with `pillow`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The pillow docs [indicate](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) `ImageGrab` module works on MacOS, but it only does the full screen, so you would have to clip that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab a specific region of the screen with PIL's `ImageGrab()` if you specify a bounding box. So, to get a 640x480 rectangle at top-left corner of screen, you can use:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

# Grab top-left rectangle with size 640px wide by 480px tall
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 639, 479))
```

So, one possibility might be to position your Chrome window to some known location, e.g. top-left corner and then capture.

You should be able to do that using Applescript adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340540/2836621) invoking it using `subprocess()`.

---

You may be able to use [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#advanced) but I haven't tried it.

---

You may be able adapt my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842314/2836621).

---

You may be able to use `locateOnScreen()` from [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to find something you know/expect to be in your Chrome window.

Comment: Not a Mac guy, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40224440/9705687) suggests that [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html) can be used to switch windows.