# Understanding ImageGrab documentation in Python package PIL

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the bbox argument in ImageGrab.grab:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html

It states:

> bbox – What region to copy. Default is the entire screen. Note that on Windows OS, the top-left point may be negative if all_screens=True is used.

There isn't enough information, so I've been hoping to find basic examples, but most are convoluted and bloated, and to be honest, the documentation is there as the first port of call, so a user should I shouldn't need to spend hours trawling through code.

What is bbox? I've managed to get it to execute, but it's not capturing the right part of the screen. It would help if the documentation stated the data type of bbox, what it should contain, and how that relates to the function.

I am seeking an example of how to use this. I am keen to learn the explicit types in variable names e.g., boundingList, or otherTuple, or myInt etc. It sounds long and drawn out, but I've spent all day working with packages that have very sparse documentation.

Comment: Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70839179/2836621

Comment: Thanks. This kind of information should be in the documentation. Not in StackOverflow. Thanks again.